# NSLog with HTTP request mutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, httprequest

I have a program in Objective-C with Xcode that gets an http request and parses the data it gets and prints the data in a tableview. The data is stored in an NSMutablearray called elementArray. It is defined in a file I have called HtmlParser.h with the line

```
@property NSMutableArray *elementArray;
```

It is synthesized in a file called HtmlParser.m with

```
@synthesize currentHTMLElement, elementArray, parser, currentNodeContent;
```

It is allocated in HtmlParser.m with the line

```
 elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

It receives objects when the program finds the objects in the HTML file. The program works fine, and the data is parsed and displayed in the tableview. However, I want to see the results from the array in the console. I tried to NSLog the array in the ViewController.m with

```
NSLog(@"Array: %@", elementArray);
```

When I do this, I get an error saying: "Use of undeclared identifier 'elementArray'. How do I fix this?

Comment: `htmlParser.elementArray`

Comment: Thanks!!! that worked, it just comes out unparsed though... but I think I can fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `elementArray` as a property on the HTML parser, so you need to say:

```
NSLog(@"Array: %@", htmlParser.elementArray);
```